# Aggregations / Summary Tables with Custom Groupings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `visits`. This table has several columns (Browser Name, Browser Version, Operating System Name, Operating System Version, Device Type, and so on). This table contains all raw data.

Example: `visits`

| id | browser_name | browser_version | os_name | os_version | device_type | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chrome | 90 | Windows | 10 | Desktop | ... |
| 2 | Chrome | 90 | Windows | 7 | Desktop | ... |
| 3 | Firefox | 60 | Windows | 10 | Desktop | ... |

On request (e.g. "I would like to have a summation based on Browser Name and Browser Version for yesterday") I create a new table with appropriate columns (if it doesn't already exist), fill it with the current values and save the last considered `visits`.`id` to not re-aggregate from id #1. (The combinations - for example Browser Name, Browser Version or simply Operating System Name - are freely selectable.)

Example: `report__2021_11_19__browser_name__browser_version`

| id | browser_name | browser_version | count | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chrome | 90 | 2 | ... |
| 2 | Firefox | 60 | 1 | ... |

Example: `report__2021_11_19__operating_system_name`

| id | operating_system_name | count | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Windows | 3 | ... |

In itself this idea works, but it doesn't feel right, because at some point there are many tables that may even contain the same data but for a "larger date span". Moreover, these have already been aggregated. (Re-aggregating millions of rows takes quite a long time; reusing already aggregated data would be quite a good idea).

Are there perhaps other common methods that I can't think of myself? Keywords or "names" would be enough for me. (For example, all data from one month into a separate table; however, there's the problem here that if I want to load data over several months, I'd have to check which tables exist and which tables I'd have to join together).

Comment: don't create tables for data that already exists make a view for that or in your case two of them

Comment: What reporting tool are you using, eg PowerBI, SSRS etc?

Comment: @nbk I create tables based on the raw data to increase the speed of the summaries. A view can get quite slow (I think) with 130 million database entries (I work with MySQL).

Comment: @Stu None. I am building my own dashboard, in use with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @0x7357 incresing the databse with that much data will make it even slower, as i sad don't do it it is a bad design

Comment: @nbk Usually a summary table has about 1/100, if not 1/1000 of the "raw data table". To claim that this is bad design is difficult without an actual mention of a reason. "Summary Tables" are often used to query reports more quickly. (After all, they are a summation based on a few selected columns - and not all of them).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating redundant tables that summarize data for fast and easy access.

First of all, there's nothing wrong about redundancy as long as it's controlled. If you don't control it correctly the redundant information may end up not in sync with the origin tables. That is, redundant table will become "stale".

If your clients are requesting information "per day", then you can create summary tables that include information per day.

For example, instead of calling your summary table `report__2021_11_19__browser_name__browser_version` you can call it `daily_browser_name__browser_version`, and it could have the following structure:

| date | browser_name | browser_version | count | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-19 | Chrome | 90 | 2 | ... |
| 2021-11-19 | Firefox | 60 | 1 | ... |
| 2021-11-20 | Chrome | 90 | 3 | ... |
| 2021-11-20 | Firefox | 60 | 5 | ... |

Instead of having the table `report__2021_11_19__operating_system_name` you can have `daily_operating_system_name` as:

| date | operating_system_name | count | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-19 | Windows | 3 | ... |
| 2021-11-20 | Windows | 2 | ... |

Querying and reporting from these tables should be simple (a single filter by date will do) and also extremely fast, assuming both tables have an index by date. As you see there's no need to create one table per day. The two tables above will produce all the requested results for any number of days.

But above all, make sure the daily process that adds records to these tables runs normally and keep them with up to date information.

Comment: The problem here is that the user can choose the "combination" himself (for example "Browser Name and Operating System Name"). In your example, I would have to cover all possible combinations and create tables for them, and it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @0x7357 If the queries are based on a big amount of data and can be done in any combination chosen by the end user (on the UI, for example), then you are looking at an OLAP solution that implements "cubes" of data. Typical SQL queries won't be fast for all possible cases.

Comment: That sounds very interesting! But that will not work with SQL? I haven't read up on "cubes" yet - sorry for the lack of knowledge.